# I'm trying to create an alternative color palette, using MUI, where according to the api it changes the background of my card

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm trying to make these colors alternate according to the pokemon's type.

But I do not know how...
Any idea!?
[here is where i am trying to create the logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljfM0.png)

[here is where the palette should be played

inside the ```<Box
sx={{ bgcolor: 'typecolor.main' }}

> 

Comment: const PokemonThumbnail = ({ id, name, image, type }) => {
  return (
    <Box
    sx={{  bgcolor: 'typecolor.main' }}
  >
    <Conteiner>
      
        <div>
          <small>#0{id}</small>
        </div>
        <IMG src={image} alt={name} />
        <div>
          <h3>{name}</h3>
          <small>Type: {type}</small>
        </div>
      
    </Conteiner>
    </Box>
  );
};

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The MUI palette is extendable, but you need to do a couple of things to create a new color and apply to your Box component.

Define a theme with a custom color variable. You can use `augmentColor()` to generate the [PaletteColor](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/f8fcae6bfc1e365aac0b82f1ae0dd2ad8438052c/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createPalette.d.ts#L49-L54) so it can be consumed in your Box then pass that new color into your component

```js
import { red } from "@mui/material/colors";

const { palette } = createTheme();
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    myCustomColor: palette.augmentColor({ color: red }),
    // Use this code if you want to use an arbitrary color
    // myCustomColor: palette.augmentColor({
    //   color: {
    //     main: "#f0000f"
    //   }
    // })
  }
});
```